# merge txt files issue with output file not being txt

Tags: python, merge, output

Below is my code to merge several txt files together.

```
import os

with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if (filename.endswith(".txt")):
            with open(filename) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

the output file 'outfile' is the merged file however it is not a txt.
I then tried

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
```

the process stucked and nothing was written into the outfile.txt
does anyone know how to fix it? my goal is to have the outfile saved as txt.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you maybe meet file lock,when there is a process open the file as `write`,other process has problem when operate that file.
you can try to bypass that file

```py
import os

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if (filename.endswith(".txt")) and filename!='outfile.txt':
            with open(filename) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```